# tcolorboxes in beamer

Tags: beamer, macros, tcolorbox

This code isn´t working. Can anyone please tell me, why this tcolorbox isn´t working? (In documentclass "article" it is working, but not in "beamer").

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169, xcolor=dvipsnames, 10pt]{beamer}

\usetheme[subsectionpage=progressbar]{metropolis}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{tcolorbox}[
    sharp corners, breakable, frame hidden, enhanced, boxrule=0pt,
    borderline west={3pt}{0pt}{red},
    segmentation style={red, line width=1.5pt, solid},
    colback=red!10,
    ]
    Test, jetzt bin ich gespannt
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

Comment: If I complete your code to be able to compile it (adding a document class, loading the necessary packages and `tcolorbox` libraries, and adding relevant environments), there are no errors and the output is what I would expect. Can you clarify what you mean by "it isn't working in beamer"? To make your question fully clear, you should provide a minimal example of code that is compilable as is and that still reproduces the problem.

Comment: I now edited my question :)

Comment: You also need to load the `tcolorbox` libraries `breakable` and `skins` since the code of your box needs them. Is that the only problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- For your definition of `\tcolorbox` style you need to load `tcolorbox` package with option `many` or `breakable` and `skins`.
- After adding `many` option and compose your code fragments into  MWE (Minimal Working Example, see it below) works fine. So it is unclear what is actually your problem.
- Off-topic, I don't see any sense that you require that `\tcolorbox` should be breakable.

Test MWE:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169, xcolor=dvipsnames, 10pt]{beamer}
\usetheme[subsectionpage=progressbar]{metropolis}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Use of the \texttt{tcolorbox}}
    \begin{tcolorbox}[
        sharp corners, %breakable, 
        frame hidden, enhanced, boxrule=0pt,
        borderline west={3pt}{0pt}{red},
        segmentation style={red, line width=1.5pt, solid},
        colback=red!10,
        ]
    \lipsum[66]
    \end{tcolorbox}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I didn´t know that I have to use "many", thanks a lot for your help! :)